# How to prove that: $\log_{{1\over 2}}(3) + \log_3\left({1 \over 2}\right) < -2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Prove that:

$$\log_{{1\over 2}}(3) + \log_3\left({1 \over 2}\right) < -2$$

Please help me solve it.

Comment: Hint: Use $\log_a (3) = \log(3)/\log(a)$ (with $\log$ being the natural logarithm) and rearrange to get: $\log(2)^2 + \log(3)^2 - 2\log(2)\log(3) > 0$. Do this look familiar, can you factorize the left hand side?

Answer (score 5):

If you know the AM-GM inequality, this is easy.

$a=\log_{\frac{1}{2}}(3)=-\log_23$ and $b=\log_3(\dfrac{1}{2})=-\log_32$.

Now $-a>0,-b>0$ so $-a-b>2\sqrt{|ab|}=2$ implying $a+b<-2$.

Comment: And so? How that: proves it (the last part)?

Comment: What else do you need?

Comment: Do you realize that $|ab|=1$?

Comment: I mean how the:  a+b<−2 proves the searched ? Also why the heck you need this: 2|ab|−−−√? The first one can be proven without it.

Comment: Your question wants to show that $a+b<-2$. I do not understand your comment at all.

Comment: You should write it the most complicated way possible do you? But thanks anyway. Glad I'm smart.

Comment: This is not a place to show your rudeness. I used $a$ and $b$ just because it is difficult to write $\log_{\dfrac{1}{2}}3$ and $\log_3\dfrac{1}{2}$ everytime: saves effort. Substitution is one of the very elementary ways in Algebra.

Answer (score 0):

$$\log_{3}(1/2)+\log_{1/2}(3)=\log_3(1/2)+\frac{\log_3(3)}{\log_3(1/2)}=$$

$$=\log_{3}(1/2)+\frac{1}{\log_3(1/2)}$$

$$=-\left(\left(\sqrt{-\log_{3}(1/2)}-\sqrt{-\frac{1}{\log_3(1/2)}}\right)^2+2\right)\le -2$$

Equality can't occur, because $\sqrt{-\log_{3}(1/2)}\neq \sqrt{-\frac{1}{\log_3(1/2)}}$.

Expressed differently:

$$\left(-\log_{3}(1/2)\right)+\left(-\log_{1/2}(3)\right)=\left(-\log_{3}(1/2)\right)+\left(-\frac{1}{\log_3(1/2)}\right)$$

$$\ge 2\sqrt{\left(-\log_3(1/2)\right)\left(-\frac{1}{\log_3(1/2)}\right)}=2$$

You may call it AM-GM, but it's the trivial inequality $a+b\ge 2\sqrt{ab}$, i.e. $\left(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}\right)^2\ge 0$, for $a,b\ge 0$. Equality won't occur, since $\left(-\log_3(1/2)\right)\neq -\frac{1}{\log_3(1/2)}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ a=\log_{3}\frac{1}{2}$, so $\;a<0$ and $\;\displaystyle\log_{\frac{1}{2}}3=\frac{\log_{3}3}{\log_3\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{a}$.

Then $(a+1)^2>0\implies a^2+1>-2a\implies a+\frac{1}{a}<-2\;\;$ (since $a<0$)